# Android: infinite loop in EditText TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two problems with this piece of code. Thanks to some nice guys here in a previous question I got it to work properly, but now I see myself in an infinite loop again and I don't get where that comes from. What I'm trying to do here is a hangman game: process a single character read in an EditText (litera) and I search for it in a word (cuvAles), then I want to replace the underscore with the respective letter.

Here's the function that's with the problem:

```
litera.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                 String ghici = litera.getText().toString();

                if(!ghici.equals("")){
                System.out.println(ghici);
                litera.setText("");

                if(cuvAles.contains(ghici)){
                    int poz = 0;
                    while(cuvAles.indexOf(ghici, poz)!= -1){
                        poz = cuvAles.indexOf(ghici);
                        String spatii = cuvant.getText().toString();
                        String spatii2 = spatii.substring(0, poz*2-1) + ghici + spatii.substring(poz*2+1, spatii.length()-2);
                        cuvant.setText(spatii2);
                    }
                }
                else gresite.append(ghici+" ");
                } 
            }   
        });
```

There are two problems here:

1) `String spatii2 = spatii.substring(0, poz*2-1) + ghici + spatii.substring(poz*2+1, spatii.length()-1);` throws a StringIndexOutOfBounds exception. I think it's the spatii.length() part, but I tried with -2 and it still doesn't work. The reason the word is not matched with the underscores is that I have spaces between them to be clear.

2) If I remove the other problem (replace the string with a constant one), I get an infinite loop (I think it's an infinite loop because the program stops responding and I see the GC in the logcat working frantically).

Answer (score 3):

Remove text change listener  before updating your edittext as it will keep calling your text change listener..

```
litera.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                 String ghici = litera.getText().toString();

     litera.removeTextChangedListener(this);            


                if(!ghici.equals("")){
                System.out.println(ghici);
                litera.setText("");

                if(cuvAles.contains(ghici)){
                    int poz = 0;
                    while(cuvAles.indexOf(ghici, poz)!= -1){
                        poz = cuvAles.indexOf(ghici);
                        String spatii = cuvant.getText().toString();
                        String spatii2 = spatii.substring(0, poz*2-1) + ghici + spatii.substring(poz*2+1, spatii.length()-2);
                        cuvant.setText(spatii2);
                    }
                }
                else gresite.append(ghici+" ");
                } 
            }   
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Any other ideas?
And about the String index out of bounds problem?